# SQL INSERT INTO WHERE NOT EXISTS with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, powerapps

I have a SQL Server database. I am looking to insert some values into multiple tables, where the data does not already exist.

Example:

Table 1

| ID | Name | Material | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aluminum | 2014 | v1 |
| 2 | Magnesium | 2013 | v2 |

I want to develop a stored procedure such that it will insert into a table the following information:

```
Aluminum | 2013
```

My current stored procedure does not let me do this as it recognizes `Magnesium | 2013` and rejects 2013 because it is being duplicated.

Also how would we compare multiple column values, for example:

```
    INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS (Material = 2014 AND Other = v3)
```

Current stored procedure:

```
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM dbo.[01_matcard24]
              WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT [01_matcard24].Element 
                                FROM dbo.[01_matcard24] 
                                WHERE dbo.[01_matcard24].Element = @new_element)
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT [01_matcard24].Material 
                                FROM dbo.[01_matcard24] 
                                WHERE dbo.[01_matcard24].Material = @new_material)
    )
    
    INSERT INTO dbo.[15_matcard24_basis-UNUSED] (Element, Material)
    VALUES (@new_element, @new_material)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, *but* there is no reason to `SELECT` actual values inside `EXISTS` clause. Usually, it's `SELECT 1`.

Comment: You can use a MERGE statement and do an update and insert at the same time (based off conditions you set in the statement) so it will either update or insert based off that logic.

Comment: @DaleK I will work on this within the next week and let you know how it goes. Just looking at the solution, it looks like this would work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rather than using an `IF` statement, keep it set-based as part of the `INSERT`
2. Create your `EXISTS` sub-query to detect unique rows, not individual columns

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[15_matcard24_basis-UNUSED] (Element, Material)
SELECT @new_element, @new_material
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.[15_matcard24_basis-UNUSED]
    WHERE Element = @new_element AND Material = @new_material
    -- AND Other = @Other
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a logic similar to what is in the attached screenshot. SQL Insert Procedure[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBe67.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask